# Unsure how to pass column variable to mean() in r

Tags: r, variables, mean

Am a newb.  Trying to code for a program.   I have a multi-column data frame.  I want to calc the mean of a column.   I want to pass to the mean() function the name of the column that i want to use for mean calc.   I have tried to pass it a character string that uses the $ symbol.  It seems R doesnt allow the string passed to be a character and wants a logical or numeric when $ is used to define the column name.   Net, am stuck.  Is there another way to do this?  Am suggestions would be appreciated.  Code and results are below

```
> ## df.final is the name of the dataframe

> car.type        <- "ford"
> col.name        <- paste("df.final","$", car.type, sep = "")

> print(col.name)
[1] "df.final$ford"

> mean(col.name, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(col.name, na.rm = TRUE) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

> mean(df.final$ford, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 3.14
```

Comment: It seems you've achieved what you wanted in the second example? df.final$ford is a column of your data. "df.final$ford" is a bunch of characters - no way to calculate the mean of that. If you want to make the data an object, do something like `datacolumn <- df.final$ford` and then `mean(datacolumn, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: A data frame is a named object and the data frame has columns that also have their own names. For example, if your data frame has the name `df.final` and it has a column called `ford` then you can select that column either with `df.final$ford` or `df.final[, "ford"]`. But "df.final$ford" is a just a string of characters. For example, try running the following: `df.final = data.frame(ford=rnorm(10)); df.final$ford; df.final[,"ford"]; names(df.final); mean(df.final$ford)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(df.final <- data.frame(ford = sample(0:100, 5), toyota = sample(0:50, 5)))
#   ford toyota
# 1   42      5
# 2   30     46
# 3   45     29
# 4   69     48
# 5   18     14
col.name
# [1] "df.final$ford"
typeof(col.name)
# [1] "character"
```

Currently, `col.name` is a character vector, so taking its mean makes no sense. Let's `parse` it into an expression:

```
temp <- parse(text = col.name)
temp
# expression(df.final$ford)
typeof(temp)
# [1] "expression"
mean(temp)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(temp) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Hmm. R still isn't happy, because taking the mean of an expression doesn't make sense either. Let's `eval`uate our expression.

```
temp <- eval(parse(text = col.name))
temp
# [1] 42 30 45 69 18
typeof(temp)
# [1] "integer"
mean(temp)
# [1] 40.8
```

Much better. So `mean(eval(parse(text = col.name)), na.rm = T)` does the trick for your example. You might also check out the useful function `?do.call` as well:

```
do.call(mean, args = list(x = temp, na.rm = T))
# [1] 40.8
```

Comment: Thx - very good explanation and walkthru.  I will study both parse() and do.call()   I had spotted do.call earlier, but had not fully understood when to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[` or `[[` to access columns by name:

```
df.final <- data.frame(ford=c(1, 2, NA), toyota=c(3, 2, 1))
car.type <- "ford"
mean(df.final[,car.type], na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 1.5
mean(df.final[[car.type]], na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 1.5
```

Comment: Thx - I liked your simple way of subsetting w/good examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, you can use `eval(·)` and `parse(·)`

```
> mean(eval(parse(text=col.name)), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 1.5
```

Comment: You should probably explain that `parse` will turn a string into an expression, while `eval` will evaluate the expression which will be equivalent to do something like `df.final$ford`